# Where does Krishna criticize Arjuna's indifference to Draupadi's disrobing?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava

The Sri Vaishnava sect has two sub-sects, Thenkalai and Vadakalai. Vadakalais follow the teachings of Vedanta Desikan, whereas Thenkalais follow the teachings of Pillai Lokacharya. My question is about Pillai Lokacharya.  In his verses 19-20 of his [Sri Vachana Bhushanam](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LBcMLi0Fn3adT_A2-Zxxdq-8CXblY6Un/view?usp=sharing), Pillai Lokacharya discusses how Sharanagati or complete surrender to Vishnu is not affected by the defects of the person surrendering.  He cites the example of Arjuna, whom Krishna helped despite all of Arjuna's defects:

> The defects of Arjuna, the sustainer of Krishna, the "intimate friend of Keshava", foremost of believers, Lord of conquerors of the senses, were, for example, compassion for and attachment to relatives and fear of killing them.  **In the opinion of Krishna, the main defect of Arjuna was the fact that he was indifferent to the insult of Draupadi.**

I'm interested in the part in bold.  My question is, where does Krishna criticize Arjuna's indifference to the disrobing of Draupadi?  Is it mentioned in the Mahabharata?

Or is this an unexpressed thought that Krishna had in his head?

Answer (score 3):

When Bhima took lead to avenge Duryodhana by killing him to draw blood and using it to wet Draupadi's hair and so on.. and he may have thought that Bhima's vow is quite an adequate response.

Moreover Arjuna's archery skill was largely under-utilized before Krishna prodded him onto coercive action to overcome his depression in order to tune him into Dharmic defence action.

That the Lord had to expound the entire human motivational path in the Gita before Arjuna in a friendly orientation.. that is sufficient expression of his impatience with Arjuna's special case as a dormant power.

Krishna even says that Arjuna's cowardice is so despicable ( *Klaibyam Hridaya dourbalyam* ..) and unbecoming of a person with so much useful military talent available but  not doing enough even in the face of provocation.

Also (at the end of convincing him on Kurukshetra battle field and while concluding ) He even goes to the extent to tell Arjuna.. "whatever I have to say I have already said;  it is now upto you further to do what you wish to do" *(Yadhaychasi kuru!)* ... even implying that Pandavas' victory would be anyhow brought about by another unknown mediocre less skilled person to whom glory of victory in battlefield would go out and and you will just remain witnessing as a helpless person to lose all credit your power and skill that you otherwise fully deserve ". I for one think this was the last straw on the camel's ( Arjuna's) buckled back that got him up with a straightened spine back to action.

Comment: Well makes sense.

Comment: OK, but I'm specifically looking for whether Krishna criticized Arjuna's indifference to the disrobing of Draupadi.

Comment: Reference is to popular Pandava Udyogam/Vijayam by Tirupati venkata kavulu (Telugu) which has no such dialogue. As far as I understood  Arjuna was silent because Bhisma and all other Kaurava seniors were standing witness to disrobing like dumb lambs and Arjuna likewise stood silent conforming  to the behaviours of grandfathers and Yudhistar.

Comment: BTW a correction: Bhima drank the blood of Duhshashana not Duryodhana.

Comment: after he fell down from Krishna's Sudarsana chakra?